# How to customize the UIContextualAction in tableview when swipe

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to create an action button with a image and text. below image provide 
an example.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEuHn.png

i have created a method like

```
public UIContextualAction ContextualFlagAction(int row)
    {
        var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal, "Flag", Handler);
            (contextualAction, view, handler) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                handler(false);
            });

        action.Image = UIImage.FromFile(ResourceIdentifiers.DocumentIcon);

        return action;
    }
```

but this is not what i need to do.

how can i customize this action as the image in the above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem showed is the image result,your code have set `action.image`
If you have a image that contains picture and label , picture is up,label is down,there will be you want.

```
public UIContextualAction ContextualFlagAction(int row)
{
    var action = UIContextualAction.FromContextualActionStyle(UIContextualActionStyle.Normal, "Flag", Handler);
        (contextualAction, view, handler) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            handler(false);
        });

    action.Image = UIImage.FromFile(ResourceIdentifiers.DocumentIcon);
    //this is your setted image
    return action;
}
```

## More info:

You can custom a TableViewCell in Xamarin.ios.

Write the following method in UITableViewCell, Rewrite **DidTransitionToState** method in viewcell, you can replace the action with button

```
 private UITableView tableViewThis;

    public TableViewCellClass(UITableView tableView)
    {
        this.tableViewThis = tableView;
        
    }
 public override void DidTransitionToState(UITableViewCellState mask)
    {
        base.DidTransitionToState(mask);
        if ((mask & UITableViewCellState.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellState.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
        {

            foreach (UIView subview in tableViewThis.Subviews)
            {
                if (subview.Class.Equals("UIContextualAction"))
                    //Delete the delete button of the system
                tableViewThis.WillRemoveSubview(subview);
                subview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

                UIButton editBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
                editBtn.Frame = new CGRect(10, 4, 50, 65);
                editBtn.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("1.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
                editBtn.AdjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false;
                editBtn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //do something you need
                };
                subview.AddSubview(editBtn);
            }
        }
    }
```

UIButton can set both Title and Image. UIButton has two properties:

**titleEdgeInsets**(top,left,bottom,right)

and **imageEdgeInsets**(top,left,bottom,right).

By setting these two, you can implement the style you need.

Comment: what is "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView" here i am little bit confused with this, because i am using c#.

Comment: I modify the answer,maybe your problem is `action.image` ，if you have a image like you want ,that will be OK.

Comment: really appreciate your help, i have done exactly what you are suggesting but the problem is with 
if (subview.Class.Name.ToString() == "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView")
                    {
                        WillRemoveSubview(subview);
                        subview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                    } 

i am getting only 2 types which are 
subview.Class.Name="UITableViewCellContentView"
subview.Class.Name="_UITableViewCellSeparatorView"

anything that i have missed?